AOT Compile of a Windows application unter .NET 8.0 not running
Trying to compile a very simple Windows forms application under .NET 8.0
Application normal compile : running
Application published via SingleFile: running
Application published via PublishAot: compiling without error but not running.
Project settings:
 <PropertyGroup>
   <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
   <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
   <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
   <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
   <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
   <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
   <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>

   <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
   <_SuppressWinFormsTrimError>true</_SuppressWinFormsTrimError>

 </PropertyGroup>

Eventlog just shows EventId = 1000 and an error of : 0xc0000409
is there an option missing?
Pit
